# How to resize p:commandButton

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How can you resize

```
<p:commandButton value="..."/>?
```

Let's assume that button looks like this:

```
+-------------+
|     ...     |
+-------------+
```

One user in discussion which is located in http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3955 suggested to use button with style

```
<p:commandButton value="..." style="width: 20px; height: 20px;font-size:80%;"/> .
```

However after doing that the text of the button is out of the button bounds:

```
+---+
|   | ...
+---+
```

I think I should use another css style.
Can you suggest me how can i resize button with another CSS style, which resizes button and moves the text right into the button?

Comment: Im trying to reproduce this in my project, but that problem is not happening here. Is there a styleClass attached to the commandButton (that maybe you forgot to describe in your post ?).

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on both 3.5 and 4.0 Primefaces projects. What is more, the code of that button is exactly like in my project. Maybe there are some global themes which can influence that text alignment... I should test it.

Comment: I am able to change the font-size and button width and height just by specifying the css style in commandbutton.

Comment: Adarsh, does the button text stay in the button after you resize it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right properties but 20px is so small. That's why the text is out of the button bounds. The larger the pixels, the larger the button. So just specify larger pixels for height and width. Then use the text-align property to align the text to right,left,center e.t.c

Try this

```
<p:commandButton value="..." style="width: 100px; height:100px; text-align: right"/>
```